# Remove 2px Gray Border Surrounds Edge IE9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, border

I'm trying to code this site (keyword trying) and I'm trying to figure out how to remove this shaded `2px` gray border the extends across the the inside of the IE9 window (at least the top, left and bottom). My margins are set to zero, so all my page elements go to the very edge of the page, but with IE9, they stop at this gray border. I have not include any code in my html to have a 2px gray border around the edge of the browser.

I don't know why this is happening in IE9, and seemingly only my webpage (other ones don't seem to have it), but it's messing up the formatting and I really need to figure out how to remove it.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a picture of what's happening in IE9 and what's happening in a real browser? Also, some code would help :)

Comment: check it out here... [Wiscuss.com](http://wiscuss.com) It shows up on every page, but you can see it on the "coming soon" home page as well. Thanks!

Comment: Could you post an IE9 screenshot though? I don't have the browser.

Comment: here.. thanks! http://i1102.photobucket.com/albums/g451/jollyjamo/borderie9.png

Comment: Did you try setting `border:0` to `*` in your css?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't specifying a doctype, as made evident by the comment on the first line:

```
<!-- Do NOT put any DOCTYPE here unless you want problems in IEs. -->
```

Because of this, IE9 goes into "quirks mode".  Add a proper doc type and it should go back into standards mode and remove the annoying grey borders.  You can test this is the issue by opening up the developer tools (F12), and change the document mode from Quirks Mode to IE9 standards.

Example HTML5 doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Charlie asked in a comment: “Did you try setting border:0 to * in your css?” This actually includes an alternative answer to the question. More specifically, the following removes the border:

```
html { border: 0; }
```

Comment: I'm quoting you from another post: `The border appears to be technically a default border around the html element, even though this cannot be seen in IE 9 inspector mode (F12), which shows 0px border for the element.`