# Remove the border around ie9 in quirks mode?

Tags: html, cross-browser, internet-explorer-9, quirks-mode

I want to know if there are any work arounds to make the 2px border disappear in ie9 even in quirks mode?
Here are some relevant links about this problem:

[Remove 2px Gray Border Surrounds Edge IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068543/remove-2px-gray-border-surrounds-edge-ie9)

http://www.dasmirnov.net/blog/controlling-how-ie9-renders-pages

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your stylesheet:

```
html { border:none; }
```

The border appears to be technically a default border around the `html` element, even though this cannot be seen in IE 9 inspector mode (F12), which shows 0px border for the element.

Comment: Nope. Its still there. I guess it is what they called compatibility. Since IE8 has that border to begin with, they forced the same in IE9 quirks mode.

Comment: Exactly what did you do? See [my demo](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/test/qb.html). Tested on IE 9.0.8112.16421 (Win 7).

Comment: Thanks Jukka for your effort, yes there is no border in your demo and your demo is in quirks mode. Just that I actually want IE8 quirks mode in IE9. Your demo is actually IE6 quirks mode in IE9. You can see the difference by adding <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" /> and you can still see the border. If you use <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=6" /> instead, you dont see the border. But yeah, sorry I did not state that clearly in my first question.